# Function not declared in scope / How use header.h, header.cpp, and main.cpp together?

Tags: c++, oop, function-call

I'm a complete beginner in C++ and I'm having trouble getting my functions declared in the `header.h` file, defined in `header.cpp`, and called in `main.cpp`. I've been looking for solutions but nothing I do seems to work. I would appreciate some input on how I can fix these issues.

Here's my code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DLinkedList.h"

int main() {
  getInfo(); //Running my function getInfo
}
```

**DLinkedList.h**

```
#ifndef DLINKEDLIST_H
#define DLINKEDLIST_H

class Node
{
  private:
      int info;

  public:
       Node* prev;
       Node* next;
       int getInfo(); //Declaring my function getInfo
       void setInfo(int value); 
};
#endif
```

**DLinkedList.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DLinkedList.h"

int getInfo() { //Defining my function getInfo
  int answer;
  std::cout << "Input the integer you want to store in the node: ";
  std::cin >> answer;
  return answer;
}
```

And the error message:

```
exit status 1
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:6:3: error: 'getInfo' was not declared in this scope
   getInfo();
   ^~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getInfo()` is not a free function. It is a member function of the class `Node`. So, it needs to be defined like this preceding with class name it belongs to using scope resolution operator i.e. `::`:

```
int Node::getInfo()
{
    // ... body ...
}
```

And, in your `main` function, you need to create an object of your class before using its member function.

For example:

```
int main()
{
    Node node;
    node.getInfo();
    return 0;
}
```

---

It's better to revise the OOP concepts and how they are implemented in C++ before writing code. Free functions and member functions are different things. Going through a proper book (or tutorial, etc.) would help you build the foundation for writing OOP code. Best of luck!